# Is there a shortcut to switch between sentry and observer ward when quickcasting?

Tags: dota-2

Since 6.84 Observer wards and Sentry wards stack in the inventory. To switch between them you have to double-click the inventory slot.

Is there a shortcut to switch between the active ward without using the mouse and double-clicking in the inventory when I have quickcast enabled on my items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double tap the 'cast' item hotkey you would press to use a ward

The default hotkeys Z,X,C,V,B,N based on the item slot (left to right, top row first)

A quickcast key cannot be used in this method. However, if you are mapping all items to quickcast, a solution is to set an alternate key combo for plain 'cast'. I recommend ALT+key. Then you can hold alt and double tap the key.

For example

quickcast item 1 = z

cast item 1 = ALT+z

With this holding ALT and double tapping z will swap wards, without impacting quickcast.

[Wiki source](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Observer_and_Sentry_Wards)

Comment: I'm using quickcast for my items, so this doesn't work

Comment: its ok if u are using quick cast u can just move curse on your hero bar(any where other thn map) and double tap the item hot key. and btw who has all 6 items on quick cast.

Comment: @Bibz I have edited my answer with a solution for quickcast, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

If Quick Cast is toggled on, you can do so by pressing the item hotkey, then clicking on your hero portrait.

This should switch your item between sentry and orbs.